# Constructor initialisation of const member fails validation

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

```
class foo 
{ 
    private:          
        const int _n;

    public: 
        foo(int n) : _n(n)
        {
            if(!nIsValid(_n))
                throw "bad value";
        }
};
```

The code above checks whether _n has a good value, but only after it's been initialised.

If one cannot allow _n - or some more complex type over which one doesn't have control - to be initialised incorrectly, how should one check whether n is good before _n is initialised, e.g., with a helper function?

```
class foo 
{ 
    private: 

        int IsValid(int & _n)
        {

            if(!IntChecker(_n))
                throw "bad value";
            else
                return _n;
        }

        const bar _n;

    public: 

        foo(int n) : _n(IsValid(n)) {}
};
```

Comment: Define "good value".

Comment: Do you have any problems with your second version?

Comment: Looks like everything [works as intended](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/098834ae680ac4b1)

Comment: It shouldn't influent on functionality in this case, but better add some difference in "_n" as function argument and "_n" as class member.

Comment: @tambre - anything that's valid - according to whatever the actual type of bar is.

Comment: If `_n` is a class object, shouldn't *its* constructor throw on an invalid construction? Otherwise it is "obviously" in a state that can be destructed again, and version 1 will do that.

Comment: @Bo Persson yes, if _n is a class object, and written correctly, this shouldn't be a problem, thus the "over which one doesn't have control" bit.

Say you were getting an _n from a database via trhird party code, and that some records may contain incomplete or incorrect or invalid information. 

Nevertheless, the third party code populates an _n (possibly incorrectly) and passes it to you for use in a foo.

Someone has to take responsibility - and the third party isn't listening.